# RavenDB returns 401 Unauthorized when putting document ID containing admin

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-http

If my document ID starts with `admin` then trying to PUT it fails with HTTP 401 Unauthorized

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/databases/mydb/docs/admin
```

`admin` + anything else also fails

prefixing `admin` e.g. `foo-admin` works

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the next build of RavenDB, thanks for the bug report.